# Creating an X by Y dimension array of (a,b) points in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've been oddly bashing my head against this problem for several hours, and would appreciate any help!

I would like to create a (for example) 100x100 array in which each index is a `(x,y)` coordinate. The overall goal here is the following:

I have x,y coordinates and would like to arrange them in a 2D space so that I can use the `np.diagonal` function to return the `(x,y)` coordinates along a line. I'll then use those `(x,y)` points to compare particular values.

The first step here is actually creating the array and I just can't seem to do it.

Comment: Could you provide some example of the code you are trying to run?  i.e. `arr[(x,y)]`, `arr[x][y]`, `arr[x,y]`, ...

Comment: You need to use a 3D array of shape `(100, 100, 2)`, e.g. `a = np.empty((100, 100, 2))`. Calling `np.diagonal(a)` will return an array of shape `(2, 100)`.

Comment: Hmmm, I think I can use Jamie's suggestion and follow it up by using zip(np.diagonal(a)[0], np.diagonal(a)[1]) to get a single list of (x,y) coordinates. All I need to do is to make sure the X and Y values are input correctly into the 3D array.

What I don't understand is why I need 100 boxes of 100x2 in order to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the numpy part of your request, but you can create the array like so:

```
coords = [[(y,x) for x in range(100)] for y in range(100)]
>>> coords[50][2]
(50,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on Jaime's suggestion:

```py
>>> x, y = numpy.mgrid[0:100, 0:100]
>>> z = numpy.array([x, y]).transpose([1,2,0])
>>> z[50, 2]
array([50,  2])
```

EDIT: Given an array of points p, of the shape (2, P), this is how you would find out which of these points are underneath diagonal n:

```py
>>> d = numpy.diagonal(z, n)
>>> cond0 = p[0, None] < d[0, :, None]
>>> cond1 = p[1, None] < d[1, :, None]
>>> good_indices_full = numpy.where(numpy.logical_and(cond0, cond1))
>>> good_indices = good_indices_full[1]
```

(I prefer to work with "good_indices", i.e. write stuff like p[:, good_indices], rather than the full tuple of arrays that numpy.where gives back).

Comment: So, this returns a single value ([50,2]) which is a problem since I will later be evaluating whether a particular point is above or below the appropriate point on the diagonal. To do this, I need every value that falls on that diagonal and not just the first value.

Comment: for me, numpy.diagonal(z) returns an array of shape (2, 100), that you should be able to use in your comparison.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the values along the diagonal, why dont you just create a 1D list?

```
import numpy as np
xs = np.linspace(1,10,100) # assuming x goes form 1 to 10
ys = np.linspace(2,3, 100) # assuming y goes from 2 to 3
xy = zip(xs, ys)
```

You no longer need the 2d array and then call the diagonal.

Comment: So the issue here is that calling the diagonal returns a single value, not every value on the diagonal which is what I need